# How to log a stored procedure error

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Scenario:** C# apps uses SQL2000. It excecute 3 stored procs within a try catch in the app. In the catch the error is suppressed. Due to some legalities, the c# code cannot be changed and implemented.

**Q:** How do I trap the actual SQL error in the stored proc into a log file or other table? @@Error returns an error message to the app but when evaluated in query analyzer it is always 0 although the 'If @@Error <> 0' does fire. I try to store the @@Error number, but it is always 0.

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

`@@ERROR` is reset to 0 when you check it.  Why?  Because it reflects the status of the last statement executed.

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0 ...
```

is a statement, and that statement succeeds, causing `@@ERROR` to be set to 0.

The proper way to examine and operate on `@@ERROR` values is as follows:

```
DECLARE @ErrorCode INT

INSERT INTO Table ...

SET @ErrorCode = @@ERROR
IF @ErrorCode <> 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ErrorLog (ErrorCode, Message)
        VALUES (@ErrorCode, 'The INSERT operation failed.')
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Haven't got an example to hand, but look at using

```
RAISERROR ... WITH LOG
```

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238452(SQL.80).aspx for more on this.

Or use:

```
xp_logevent {error_number, 'message'} [, 'severity']
```

to write to the event log.  More details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260695(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Didn't try it myself but I guess you can monitor the errors with **Sql Server Profiler**.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoreProcedureName] 
(
parameters 
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT On
    BEGIN TRY               
        --type your query   

    End Try
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
                ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
                ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
                ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
                ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
            RETURN -1
    END CATCH
End
```